# How to handle override rowselected event in custom render xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want to override the below method in the custom renderer. All i want to do is show or hide the checkmark on select and deselect.

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath   indexPath)
{
 // Do something
}
```

## Custom Renderer code below

```
 public class StandardViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
 {
    public override UIKit.UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UIKit.UITableViewCell reusableCell, UIKit.UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
        switch (item.StyleId)
        {
            case "checkmark":
                cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
                break;
            default:
                cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
                break;
        }
        return cell;
    }
```

i want to do something like below. What method should i override to achieve this.

```
    public override UIKit.UITableViewCell RowSelected(Cell item, UIKit.UITableViewCell reusableCell, UIKit.UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
        cell.Accessory=UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
        return cell;
     }


}
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a `UITableViewDelegate` subclass in a custom `ListViewRenderer`:

```
public class CheckedListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
{
    class CheckedUITableViewDelegate : UITableViewDelegate
    {
        public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = tableView.CellAt(indexPath);
            cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
        }

        public override void RowDeselected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = tableView.CellAt(indexPath);
            if (cell != null) cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control?.Delegate == null)
        {
            Control.Delegate = new CheckedUITableViewDelegate();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

#### **Note:**

This selection method of the accessory view does not take into account selected cells scrolling out of the view, multi-selection, nor does it take *cell recycling* into consideration either. You would need to maintain a secondary data source upon selection and deselection to handle those three items...

Comment: this doesn't work for me as there are many custom list view controls in my project with grids in them etc. Due to which the conversion is failing and i am not able to use. I think i will have to find some other way.

Comment: @NewbieIOS You can always subclass `ListView` for the cases that you need the toggle the `Checkmark` and register the custom renderer for only that renderer.

Comment: I am getting this exception System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.CellTableViewCell.GetNativeCell (UIKit.UITableView tableView, Xamarin.Forms.Cell cell, System.Boolean recycleCells, System.String templateId) [0x0000c] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Cells\CellTableViewCell.cs:50
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.TableViewModelRenderer.GetCell (UIKit.UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)